# Angular: canActivate : Property 'map' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

**Code:**

Imported map and switchMap

```
 import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

canActivate code for route guard:

```
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.userObservable
      .pipe(switchMap((user: firebase.User) => this.userService.fetch(user.uid))
      .map((user) => user.isSeller));
  }
```

I am getting an error Property 'map' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction'. Please see screenshots below.

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

**My attempt:** Wrapping map with pipe does not help.

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.userObservable
      .pipe(switchMap((user: firebase.User) => this.userService.fetch(user.uid))
      .pipe(map((user) => user.isSeller)));
  }
```

I am not sure if this is correct syntax or not but the above one also throws error.

[image]

May I know what is causing this error. Thanks in Advance

Comment: *Wrapping map with pipe does not help.*? Did you import `map()` like: `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: Yes I have imported map and switchmap from rxjs as you can see in the screenshots. But may be my syntax is wrong. I have now edited my question. Added code for pipe around map

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the info. Much appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry about the comment saying `pipe()` doesn't return an Observable. In fact they do, that is why we can subscribe to it. I had not chained pipe before this in the way you describe. I will have a look but yeah the correct way would be the ones sugested in the answers.

Comment: What was the error you were getting when you wrapped the `map()` in the second `pipe()`?

Comment: @xyz The same error: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction'.

Comment: Okay so you were having the pipe inside another but not chaining it, had you done: `pipe(switchMap((user: firebase.User) => this.userService.fetch(user.uid)))
.pipe(map((user) => user.isSeller));` It should had been fine. Even though it is not required to be done this way. You can try and have a look

Comment: @xyz. I did try chaining the pipes. But it was throwing the same error. May be because of the type of data returned from first pipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That line of code with [RxJS's map operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) should be nested within your `pipe()`.

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.userObservable
      .pipe(
        switchMap((user: firebase.User) => this.userService.fetch(user.uid)),
        map((user) => user.isSeller)
     )
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

When using pipe please add all operators inside as separated with commas.

```
 canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.userObservable
      .pipe(switchMap((user: firebase.User) => this.userService.fetch(user.uid))
      , map((user) => user.isSeller));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because you are invoking `map` on the function returned by `switchMap` (which does not have a member called `map`), as you are incorrectly closing the parenthesis.

To use pipeable operators, one would normally concatenate invocations of them as arguments of `pipe`:

```
obs$.pipe(op1(...),op2(...),...,opN(...));
```

Applied to your code, you need to refactor into:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.userObservable
      .pipe(
         switchMap((user: firebase.User) => this.userService.fetch(user.uid)),
         map(user => user.isSeller)
      );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I didn't quite get the explanation, woudn't switchMap be returning an Observable? I tried chaining pipes and they work fine. Would you have a look? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfmxzb

Comment: Okay, I see now. The user had a `pipe()` within another `pipe()`

Comment: @xyz Rxjs operators are _high order functions_: they return functions when invoked. When using `pipe`, those functions are collected and invoked sequentially.